# Which members of PySequenceMethods are optional?

Tags: python, sequence, python-c-api

I'd like to allow my extension objects to be passed into Python's `len()` function, and I understand the way to do this is to implement the `sq_length` member of `PySequenceMethods`, but right now I don't have time to implement *all* the methods of the sequence protocol, and I can't figure out which of the methods are optional and which (if any) are required.

The [documentation for `tp_as_sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.tp_as_sequence) does not mention anything about optional members.

The [documentation for `PySequenceMethods`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#sequence-structs) explicitly states that `sq_item`, `sq_ass_item`, `sq_contains`, `sq_inplace_concat`, and `sq_inplace_repeat` can be left to `NULL`.

Further, the [documentation for `sq_item`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PySequenceMethods.sq_item) implies that `sq_length` can also be left to `NULL`:

> If `sq_length` is *NULL*, the index is passed as is [...]

Which leaves `sq_concat` and `sq_repeat`. I'd be surprised if it weren't safe to also set these to `NULL`, given that you can do so for all the other members (including `sq_item`, and `sq_length`, both of which seem more fundamental to the concept of a sequence than the others), but is this assumption actually correct?

If it's *not* safe to leave them `NULL`, is it safe to implement them simply to set an error stating that these two functions are not supported and return `NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of them are optional.

Setting `sq_item` to `NULL` means that `PySequence_Check()` fails, and so it isn't really a sequence - I don't know how "optional" you want to consider that.

All of the `PySequence_*` methods check for `NULL` pointers and will just set a Python `TypeError` rather than crashing, so it's safe to set these members to `NULL`. Just to show the two you were unsure about:

[`PySequence_Concat`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a24107b04c1277e3c1105f98aff5bfa3a98b33a0/Objects/abstract.c#L1564) and [`PySequence_Repeat`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a24107b04c1277e3c1105f98aff5bfa3a98b33a0/Objects/abstract.c#L1589) both have code of the form:

```
if (m && m->sq_repeat)
    return m->sq_repeat(o, count);
```

It's pretty straightforward to go through the rest of the functions and see that they use the same pattern.